# is it possible to run a function automatically on startup with pysimpleGUI

Tags: function, startup, pysimplegui

I have a function that checks my database to see if any patients need to be sent reminder text today.
I'd like this to run automatically on startup but don't know how.
I'm new to pysimpleGUI and have little coding experience.
Any advice greatly appreciated, tks, Ian

I've looked at the pysimplegui.org website but couldn't find anything
I've also watched a few videos on youtube to see if anyone covers this problem
I then tried chatGPT, it said to use sg.StartupTK(my_function) but I got errors I don't understand

This is my function which I'm trying to call on startup

```
def text_today():
    conn = create_connection(database)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM PATIENT WHERE REPEAT_DATE = ?", 
    (string_of_today,)) #checks database to see if any patients 
                        #repeat date is today
    results = c.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        first_name = row[1]
        repeats_left = row[8]
        repeats_left +-1
        c.execute("UPDATE PATIENT SET REPEATS_LEFT =? WHERE 
        FIRST_NAME = ?", (repeats_left,first_name,))
        conn.commit()
        
        print(repeats_left)
        print(first_name)
        print(results)
        flow_twilio(first_name,repeats_left) 
        """this function sends msg via twilio 
           to let patient know repeat is due 
           and how many repeats are left"""
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Function `sg.StartupTK` NOT user callable, it creates the window (for real) lays out all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to demo how to remind you that the people whose birthday in next month.

```py
import datetime
import calendar
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def func(data):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    next_month = datetime.date(today.year, today.month+1, 1).month
    month = calendar.month_name[next_month]
    return [item for item in data if month in item[1]]

headings = ['President', 'Date of Birth']

data = [
    ['Ronald Reagan', 'February 6'],
    ['Abraham Lincoln', 'February 12'],
    ['George Washington', 'February 22'],
    ['Andrew Jackson', 'March 15'],
    ['Thomas Jefferson', 'April 13'],
    ['Harry Truman', 'May 8'],
    ['John F. Kennedy', 'May 29'],
    ['George H. W. Bush', 'June 12'],
    ['George W. Bush', 'July 6'],
    ['John Quincy Adams', 'July 11'],
    ['Garrett Walker', 'July 18'],
    ['Bill Clinton', 'August 19'],
    ['Jimmy Carter', 'October 1'],
    ['John Adams', 'October 30'],
    ['Theodore Roosevelt', 'October 27'],
    ['Frank Underwood', 'November 5'],
    ['Woodrow Wilson', 'December 28'],
]
col_widths = list(map(lambda y:max(y)+2, map(lambda x:map(len, x), zip(*data))))

items = func(data)

sg.theme('DarkGreen')
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Birthday in next month !')],
    [sg.Table(values=items, headings=headings, auto_size_columns=False,
        col_widths=col_widths, expand_x=True, expand_y=True, justification='center',
        key='-TABLE-')],
]

sg.Window("Title", layout).read(close=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I can see in the layout you set values=items

Comment: I've added my function to give an idea what I'm trying to do